# A summation equation

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, summation, recursion

How would you solve this equation?

$$\frac{1^4}{2\sqrt{x} + 1} + \frac{2^4}{2\sqrt{x} + 3} + \frac{3^4}{2\sqrt{x} + 5} + \frac{4^4}{2\sqrt{x} + 7} = 50$$

I know the answer is $1/4$, and I know you can simply solve this by computing LCM, but it must have a simpler solution. I tried to simplify all as a summation like $\sum_{n=0}^{n=3} \frac{(n+1)^4}{2\sqrt{x}+2n+1} = 50$ but I don't really figure out how to continue from this, could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you could somehow stumble upon the solution $1/4$, you could show it's the only solution by showing the left hand side is a decreasing function of $x$.

Comment: I suppose if you were lucky it might spontaneously occur to you to rewrite it as
$$
\frac{1^4}{\sqrt{x} + \frac12} + \frac{2^4}{\sqrt{x} + \frac32} + \frac{3^4}{\sqrt{x} + \frac52} + \frac{4^4}{\sqrt{x} + \frac72} = 100,
$$
whereupon it might strike you that taking $\sqrt{x} = \frac12$ makes it true ... I'll get me coat. :)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley thank you!